# Is there any difference between "with an eye on/to/towards"?

Tags: prepositions, difference

I have these 3 entries in my dictionary ([multitran.ru](http://www.multitran.ru/c/m.exe?a=1&SHL=2)):

1. with an eye on sth
2. with an eye to sth
3. with an eye towards sth

which all seem to mean some intent. Are they just synonyms?

Comment: You are enquiring about a very interesting subject, but without more details the question is on a path to be closed. Please have a look at [this meta post](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please) and the [help centre](http://ell.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) for information on how to improve it (adding your opinion and research would help a lot). Oh, and welcome to the ELL :-)

Comment: Yes, please show what you think they mean.

Comment: Sorry, an additional question - can you please specify which dictionary? Thanks!

Comment: @Lucky http://www.multitran.ru/

Comment: I've tried it and I see what you mean, it does return similar expressions in Russian for all three (although I don't speak the language). I've voted to reopen, now we just need a few more votes. In the meanwhile I suggest running all three expressions through a monolingual dictionary. You can find some [here](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/735/resources-for-learning-english/739#739)

Comment: The standard abbreviation for something in dictionaries is sth ( without a dot), not smth. (5 signs) are no abbreviation.

Answer (score 5):

There is a difference...

Keeping an eye on Smith, for example,  means that Smith either is, or should be, watched (figuratively or literally). It can have positive or negative connotations: "Keep an eye on Smith - he's going to be the next big thing" or "Keep an eye on Smith - he can't be trusted"

To/towards however usually implies something happening in the future "We're planning the work with an eye towards Smith getting the job" or "With an eye to the World Cup in Qatar, we need to do more hot weather training"